# magento customer module add new table and config show error "Fatal error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on a non-object" in admin page

Tags: magento-1.9, php, customer

I Create a new table with the name of "directory_country_city",then i config the new table in my config.xml its placed in "FederalLawyer/app/code/local/Federallawyer/Customer/config.xml"

```
The code in config.xml
----------------------
<config>
    <modules>
        <Federallawyer_Customer>
            <version>1.1.5</version>
        </Federallawyer_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer_edit_tabs>Federallawyer_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tabs</customer_edit_tabs>
                    <customer_grid>Federallawyer_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Grid</customer_grid>
                    <customer_edit_tab_account>Federallawyer_Customer_Block_Adminhtml_Customer_Edit_Tab_Account</customer_edit_tab_account>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <form_register>Federallawyer_Customer_Block_Form_Register</form_register>
                    <account_navigation>Federallawyer_Customer_Block_Customer_Account_Navigation</account_navigation>
                    <address_book>Federallawyer_Customer_Block_Address_Book</address_book>
                    <form_edit>Federallawyer_Customer_Block_Form_Edit</form_edit>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>

            <federallawyer_customer>
                <class>Federallawyer_Customer_Block</class>
            </federallawyer_customer>

        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <data>Federallawyer_Customer_Helper_Data</data>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
        </helpers>

        <models>
            <customer>
                <rewrite>
                    <customer>Federallawyer_Customer_Model_Customer</customer>
                </rewrite>
            </customer>
            <customer>
                <class>Federallawyer_Customer_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>customer_resource</resourceModel>
            </customer>
            <customer_resource>
                <class>Federallawyer_Customer_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <cities><table>directory_country_city</table></cities>
                </entities>
            </customer_resource>

        </models>

          <resources>
            <federallawyer_customer_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Federallawyer_Customer</module>
                    <class>Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                </setup>
            </federallawyer_customer_setup>
        </resources>

    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <customer>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <federallawyer_customer before="Mage_Customer">Federallawyer_Customer</federallawyer_customer>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </customer>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Federallawyer_Customer before="Mage_Adminhtml">Federallawyer_Customer_Adminhtml</Federallawyer_Customer>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>

    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <customer>
                    <file>federallawyer/customer.xml</file>
                </customer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

    <adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
            <customer>
                <file>federallawyer/customer.xml</file>
            </customer>
        </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
</config>

But it throw an error in admin end "Fatal error: Call to a member function addFieldToFilter() on a non-object "
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot understand why you have using

`Model,resource model's, prefix` identifier as `customer`.
Also you have using

```
.....
    <global>
         <models>
.....
            <customer> <!-- Model Prefix identifier -->
                <class>Federallawyer_Customer_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>customer_resource</resourceModel>
            </customer>
            <customer_resource> <!-- Resource Model Prefix identifier -->
                <class>Federallawyer_Customer_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <cities><table>directory_country_city</table></cities>
                </entities>
            </customer_resource>
....................
        </models>
  .......        
    </global>
```

Which is already element of `Mage_Customer` module

That make issue.You need to change  to all this.

.....

```
    <global>
         <models>
.....
            <federallawyercustomer> <!-- change here -->
                <class>Federallawyer_Customer_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>federallawyercustomer_resource</resourceModel> <!-- change here -->
            </federallawyercustomer>
            <federallawyercustomer_resource> <!-- change here -->
                <class>Federallawyer_Customer_Model_Resource</class>
                <entities>
                    <cities><table>directory_country_city</table></cities>
                </entities>
            </federallawyercustomer_resource>
....................
        </models>
  .......        
    </global>
```